# JMeter Load testing Errors: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHost ConnectException java.net.SocketTimeoutException ConnectTimeoutException errors

Tags: java, windows, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am using apache JMeter version 5.5.
I am trying to run the sample test with more than 500 users. The test runs up to 200 users without any error after that start throwing list of below errors
`Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException` 
[please refer the image for the error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jcAi.png)

errors are like this:

case 1:[Time out error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZLL1.png)
case 2: [Read Time out error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS0LT.png)

I have tried the below solutions:
1 enable and check of keep-alive button
2 setting the time outs up to 100000 milliseconds

how to overcome this errors?
Is errors from JMeter script or Server side ?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are from the server side. By default JMeter waits for response forever, however there could be timeouts which are set on [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) or OS level.

You can try specifying explicit larger timeouts under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler. If you have > 1 HTTP Request samplers and want to apply the timeouts to all of them - go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices)

[image]